# Selection of multiple values in ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox

What I have is two indexes. I want to select both the indexes from a ListBox but when I use SelectedIndex = count (that's where the index is stored), only the last index is selected. I have also tried using selectedItems.add(count) but the result doesn't show up. Here's my code:

```
if (checkedvalues_forclass[j] == subjectid_forreverse[count])
{
    listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(count);
    //or
    listBox1.SelectedIndex=count;  
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is the following:

```
  listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended;
  listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(listBox1.Items[firstindex]);
  listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(listBox1.Items[secondindex]);
```

Comment: thank u very much for d help.......really appreciate it.....could u help me in another problem.........after i write the above commands the items get selected but it also adds up.wat i want is the items to be selected but not to be added.

Comment: So... you want the items to be selected but don't get pushed in the SelectedItems collection of your ListBox? Then you will have to write your own custom ListBox that simulates the item behavior of being selected without adding them to the SelectedItems collection.

Comment: if (!duplicateremover.Contains(checkedvalues_forclass[j]))
                        {
                            duplicateremover.Add(checkedvalues_forclass[j]);
                            if (checkedvalues_forclass[j] != null)
                            {
                                result_subject += checkedvalues_forclass[j] + ",";
                            }
                        }                                         yes thank you i did it.......thank you all for ur help..

Answer (score 0):

These two links might help you:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/06/02/sync-multi-select-listbox-with-viewmodel/

http://www.gbogea.com/2010/01/02/mvvm-multiselect-listbox

Comment: thank u very much for d help.......really appreciate it.....could u help me in another problem.........after i write the above commands the items get selected but it also adds up.wat i want is the items to be selected but not to be added.